# Heavy load on a simple query

Tags: mysql

Two tables exists:

`maindata = id, devid, value` (10M rows)
`djournal = id, devid, md_id_begin, md_id_end, state` (10k rows)

I want to select all from `maindata` for certain `devid` except rows having wrong `state`:

```
SELECT md.* 
  FROM maindata AS md
  LEFT JOIN djournal AS dj
    ON md.id BETWEEN dj.md_id_begin AND dj.md_id_end
    AND md.devid = dj.devid
  WHERE md.devid = 123456789
    AND dj.state <> 'idle'
  ORDER BY md.id ASC;
```

Given query produce exactly what I want, but sloooooow. All possible indices has been created.
Sure it's easy to store `state` field directly in the `maindata` table, but it's curious why that query is so slow and is any workaround exists?

Comment: Creating "all possible indices" is rarely a good idea.  If you have come anywhere near creating all the *possible* indices, you have almost certainly made every query slower.  Could you also add the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` of that query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for disturbance, people, no solution exists for that problem. That's not a problem at all, that's a normal sql-engine's behaviour. I've try to explain why.
Let we have two sets:

```
mysql> select * from Q;      mysql> select * from R;
+----+------+                +----+------+
| id | val  |                | id | val  |
+----+------+                +----+------+
|  1 | a    |                |  1 | a    |
|  2 | b    |                |  2 | b    |
|  3 | c    |                |  3 | c    |
|  4 | d    |                |  4 | d    |
|  5 | e    |                |  5 | e    |
+----+------+                +----+------+
```

Let make a JOIN with no condition:

```
mysql> SELECT Q.val AS Qval, R.val AS Rval FROM Q JOIN R;
+------+------+
| Qval | Rval |
+------+------+
| a    | a    |
| b    | a    |
| c    | a    |
| d    | a    |
| e    | a    |
| a    | b    |
| b    | b    |
| c    | b    |
| d    | b    |
| e    | b    |
| a    | c    |
| b    | c    |
| c    | c    |
| d    | c    |
| e    | c    |
| a    | d    |
| b    | d    |
| c    | d    |
| d    | d    |
| e    | d    |
| a    | e    |
| b    | e    |
| c    | e    |
| d    | e    |
| e    | e    |
+------+------+
25 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Let's straighten JOIN by "=" condition:

```
mysql> SELECT Q.val AS Qval, R.val AS Rval FROM Q JOIN R ON Q.val = R.val;
+------+------+
| Qval | Rval |
+------+------+
| a    | a    |
| b    | b    |
| c    | c    |
| d    | d    |
| e    | e    |
+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And when we JOIN on ">" we get:

```
mysql> SELECT Q.val AS Qval, R.val AS Rval FROM Q JOIN R ON Q.val > R.val;
+------+------+
| Qval | Rval |
+------+------+
| b    | a    |
| c    | a    |
| d    | a    |
| e    | a    |
| c    | b    |
| d    | b    |
| e    | b    |
| d    | c    |
| e    | c    |
| e    | d    |
+------+------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Lax condition produce lax result. Complex condition reduce the resulting set, but significantly increase the amount of calculations. When we JOIN on BETWEEN or < or > we get huge temporary tables for intermediate results - with no indices, searched by filesort.

So, joining sets by something else than "=" - is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You just have an index problem.

You didn't published the database structure, but if you ask this question, this is because you don't know much about databases (because every decent db server can show you where the query spend its time).

Your missing indexes are probably on `md_id_begin`, `md_id_end` as well as `state`. Just a guess.
Indexing `id` could also be a very good idea if you didn't.

Comment: Sure I know what are indices standing for, and I've try literally every index I can imagine. I've even play with field order in complex indices and also have try to give an index hints to the engine. Seems that mysql fails on a JOIN when it performed with BETWEEN statement.

Comment: So if you are acclimated to MySQL, use EXPLAIN EXTENDED as stated by Ladadadada. This gives sometimes ideas about what is wrong. If you think this is BETWEEN, just replace it with a "<" test and a ">" test. And, in some rare cases, MySQL don't order the table correctly when doing joins: use STRAIGHT_JOIN and try both join order. Hope this will be of any help. Note: I didn't saw "all possible indices has been created", sorry for the delay.